# Why math.simplify("1e-10").toString() of math.js returns 0?

Tags: javascript, math.js

I have question about the function simplify from [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/simplify.html) library for JavaScript. The function returns `0` for very small numbers. 
e.g.:

```
math.simplify("1e-10").toString(); // returns 0
math.simplify("sin(1.5)*1e-10").toString(); // returns 0
```

It is not much good for computations with small numbers.
Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm no JavaScript expert but does that method understand scientific syntax? Would it be able to get that `1e-10` is meant to be `0.0000000001` and not `1 * e - 10` ([definition of e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)))? Does it work for numbers like "1e-1", "1e+10" etc.?

Comment: Thanks but math.simplify("0.0000000001").toString(); gives still 0, only math.simplify("1e-7").toString(); returns "1 / 10000000"

Comment: In that case the only other option that comes to my mind could be a precision matter. From the documentation it seems that there is a configurable `epsilon` which might have been changed from the default value `1e-14` and because of this the library might decide that 1e-10 is basically equal to 0.

Comment: Is it just a memory thing? The transition happens when you go from 1e-7 to 1e-8. Maybe the JavaScript engine is rounding down due to the  information being stored in 8 bits.

Comment: Trying to change epsilon: 1e-32 and  precision: 164 but still no effect. I am not shure about 8 bits problem cause in javascript i suppose 52 bits for Value 11 bits for exponent 1 bit for sign as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in math.js. I've opened an issue here:

https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/813